# How to tell rspec to run without pending tests output?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way (maybe some key) to tell rspec to skip pending tests and don't print information about them?

I have some auto generated tests like

```
pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
```

I run "bundle exec rspec spec/models --format documentation" and get somethin like this:

```
Rating
  allows to rate first time
  disallow to rate book twice

Customer
  add some examples to (or delete) /home/richelieu/Code/first_model/spec/models/customer_spec.rb (PENDING: No reason given)

Category
  add some examples to (or delete) /home/richelieu/Code/first_model/spec/models/category_spec.rb (PENDING: No reason given)
......
```

I want to keep this files, cause I gonna change them later, but for now I want output like:

```
Rating
  allows to rate first time
  disallow to rate book twice

Finished in 0.14011 seconds
10 examples, 0 failures, 8 pending
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [tags](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/command-line/tag-option#filter-examples-with-a-simple-tag) -

You could do something like this in your test file

```
describe "the test I'm skipping for now" do     
  it "slow example", :skip => true do
    #test here
  end
end
```

and run your tests like this:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/models --format documentation --tag ~skip
```

where the `~` character excludes all tests with the following tag, in this case `skip`

Comment: Thx. So u can't just skip all pending? Only way to add flags to each?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure - try just running `bundle exec rspec spec/models --format documentation --tag ~skip` without changing your tests and see if it works, if not, just add tags to the tests that should be skipped

Comment: @GriwMF, rather than adding the skip tag on the command line, you can create a global rspec config file at ~/.rspec with '--tag "~skip" in it. As a bonus, this will skip them in guard as well.

Comment: Just adding my two cents here: in spec_helper (if using a spec_helper file) `config.filter_run_excluding skip: true` I usually add it directly underneath the opening `RSpec.configure do |config|` line. Doesn't that achieve the same result?

Comment: Add `--tag ~skip` to project `.rspec` file to set as default for repo.

Answer (score 7):

For posterity: you can suppress output of pending tests in the main body of documentation output by creating a custom formatter.

(For RSpec 3). I made a house_formatter.rb file in my spec directory like this:

```
class HouseFormatter < RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter
   RSpec::Core::Formatters.register self, :example_pending
   def example_pending(notification); end
end
```

Then I added the following line to my .rspec file:

```
--require spec/house_formatter
```

Now I can call the formatter with `rspec --format HouseFormatter <file>`.

Note that I still get the "pending tests" section at the end.  But as far as I am concerned, that's perfect.

Comment: you can add `def dump_pending(notification); end` to squelch the pending paragraphs. and use ProgressFormatter instead of DocumentationFormatter.

Comment: Thank you! I have created an issue on rspec github repo as I think there should be a command line option to do just this. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2377

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš ...aaaand, they closed it.  :(  They did post a better fix than mine, though, so I've cheekily made that code a new answer to this question.  Maybe that will help someone...

Answer (score 6):

This is the official "fix" posted for this problem on Github in response to the [issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/issues/2377) Marko raised, and as such it deserves a seperate answer.

This is probably the better answer, too; mine is pretty fragile.  Credit for this should go to [Myron Marston](https://github.com/myronmarston) on the Rspec team.

> You can implement this for yourself pretty easily:
>
> ```
> module FormatterOverrides
>   def example_pending(_)
>   end
>
>   def dump_pending(_)
>   end
> end
>
> RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter.prepend FormatterOverrides
> ```
>
> Or if you only want to silence block-less examples:
>
> ```
> module FormatterOverrides
>   def example_pending(notification)
>     super if notification.example.metadata[:block]
>   end
>
>   def dump_pending(_)
>   end
> end
>
> RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter.prepend FormatterOverrides
> ```
>
> Or, if you just want to filter out block-less pending examples (but
>   still show other pending examples):
>
> ```
> RSpec.configure do |c|
>   c.filter_run_excluding :block => nil
> end
> ```

Comment: where do you add these modules?

Comment: @AustinRichardson  You can put it in spec_helper.rb -- take a look at the github thread behind the word "issue" above.

Comment: Put this in my spec helper with no affect. Any advice? I am using parallel_tests. Maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: In fact, just ran without parallel_tests and still output pending.